# How I validate my Django Form with a File Upload

Tags: jquery, django, forms, django-forms

I want to validate my form but it uploads everytime the whole file before I get the feedback from Django which field is correct or incorrect.

Can I prevent the upload or validate it one some other ways like on the front-end. That I upload first if the form if it's correct.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use frontend javascript form validation?

Comment: There was this stackoverflow post a while ago which talks about django javascript form validation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318989/django-javascript-form-validation At the end of the day you are going to have to do validation in JS first then do the post upon sucess.

Answer (score 1):

The file uploads because when you submit the form, the request sent to the server includes the file.

One way you may approach this if you need to validate other fields first is maybe use some Ajax or as you suggest, front-validation with javascript. But remember, front-end validation is never enough. You can have front-end validation for performance purposes and client satisfaction but always perform a full server side validation.

This [link](http://alexkehayias.tumblr.com/post/14020155360/django-form-validation-ajax) may help you with what you want.

Hope this helps!