# what is the best way to check django form errors in javascript before submitting?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, error-checking

Actually I need a method which have same error message in javascript validation (client side) and in my django form validation (server side).

I search for any django library for this but I didn't find any. This is the most relative question I founded in SO, but it seems not helpful:

[Django Javascript form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318989/django-javascript-form-validation)

Do you know any django library for this or if not what is the best method to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why  do you want javascript to do that when the form does a good job fr you ? You can use the jquery's validation plugin to achieve though

Comment: It's more convenient for user (because check after submitting is costly).

Comment: Basically, you can use a jquery plugin like : http://jqueryvalidation.org/, and before submit, validate the form fields

Comment: Why not just use HTML5 validation? Its quite good, that way, you barely have to even deal with erroneous input.

Comment: HTML5  validation (with the 'pattern' attribute) doesn't work with textarea unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any existing library to do this easily, so I use a workaround.

Django form errors are in list format. Its difficult to transfer a list of dict from Django to JS. I have a function that comes in handy. This function *(convertErrorsToDict)* concatenates all errors per parameter together into 1 error.:

**views.py:**

```
def convertErrorsToDict(errors): #previously errors={f1:[er1]}. make it {f1:'er1'} so we can render nicely
    #converts form errors from list to dictionary
    errors2={}
    for f in errors:
        errors2[f]='.'.join(errors[f])
    return (errors2)


def setPassword(request):
    your_form=FormName();
    context={}
    errors=convertErrorsToDict(your_form.errors)
    context['errors']=errors;
    return render(request,'htmlFileName.html',context)
```

**FileName.html:**

```
{% load jsonify %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var errors={{errors|jsonify}};    
</script>
```

**FileName.js**
In js file we can now directly use `errors` as a variable.

```
console.log(errors.para1) //para1 is first para in the form. eg first_name
console.log(errors.para2)
```

This feature is useful when we need complete control on form errors content.